# "No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider" when building über-jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, neo4j, lucene, executable-jar

I have manually downloaded and added the libraries log4j, jsoup and neo4j for a project in Intellij Idea.
Before adding neo4j, I could build a jar as an artifact with all the libraries extracted to it so i could directly copy it somewhere and run with `java -jar file.jar`.

When I run the application in IntelliJ Idea it always works!

Now i get the following error when running the jar:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:314)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:268)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)
        at sun.misc.JarIndex.getJarIndex(JarIndex.java:137)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:839)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:831)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:830)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:803)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:530)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:520)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:519)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:492)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getNextLoader(URLClassPath.java:457)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:211)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:365)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I already searched for the error and found that a library seems to be signed and I can't just pack it into another jar, because it thinks it was modified then.
The suggested solution was to exclude the signing files through the build system.
I tried to manually delete the BCKEY.dsa and the BCKEY.sf files (only signing files in META-INF folder) in the resulting jar but then I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /home/xuiqzy/Documents/uni/4.Semester/PRG_practicum/WikiXtractor/data
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:40)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.lambda$createDatabaseCreator$0(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:183)
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:65)
        at de.bened.wikixtractor.DatabaseManager.initialize(DatabaseManager.java:43)
        at de.bened.wikixtractor.Main.main(Main.java:83)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@5c67716' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:99)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: No dependency satisfies type class org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:71)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Dependencies.resolveDependency(Dependencies.java:67)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:418)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
        ... 13 more
```

I also searched that error, a `META-INF/services/org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensionFactory` file exists in my jar, there are also the jars `lucene-analyzers-commen`, `lucene-codecs`, `lucene-core`, `lucene-queryparser`, `neo4j-lucene-index` and `neo4j-lucene-upgrade` all integrated in the über-jar and the build in IntelliJ Idea seems to have enough dependencies, too.

So I'm a bit clueless why the jar doesn't work as opposed to the build in the IDE.
Long term I'm willing to switch to a build system but for now:

Is there a way to get the jar to run?

Any help or pointers in the right direction are appreciated! :)

Comment: What's the contents of META-INF/services/org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensionFactory ? Typically this is an issue where there are multiple such source files and the repackaging overwrites all but one. Using the shade maven plugin fixes that where it's able to merge such files instead of overwriting.

Comment: No solution? Same problem.